# Stop app from freezing when executing heavy for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `for` loop in my application that runs after every 30 seconds. This `for` loop runs a very heavy processes (related to `MapKit`, setting coordinates/updating properties of large amount of objects). The issue is, Whole application freezes for 1-2 seconds while this process executes.

Does Swift provide any functionality at all to stop this freezing from happening? I've done some reading on the matter and have read that "threads" might be the answer.

Any ideas as to how I can stop my app from freezing when executing the code?

Comment: Threads are the answer to this problem. Please show the research you've done as well as any attempts you've made at solving the problem and the specific part that you're getting stuck on.

Comment: @0x7fffffff https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swift%20threads - That's part of the problem. The first results that show are to do with running things in the background which is not what I'm looking for. I would just like to see a simple example usage of threads in Swift

Comment: Why does running something on a background thread as suggested by the first link referenced in your google search not help? Probably it doesn't fit your use-case, but you should explain why it doesn't fit so that people can suggest alternates..

Comment: One problem with iOS is that "running in the background" has multiple meanings.  What you need is how to run something on a background queue (i.e. not the main thread); what you don't need, for this purpose, is how to run something while your app is in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

// set your long task here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI once finished the background task
    }
}
```